# Static Class & Static Method

Tags: c#, .net

What is different between static method in static class and static method in non-static class?

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference.
Not between the methods anyway.

Answer (score 5):

For the majority of scenarios they are essentially equivalent features.  The one notable difference is that only a `static` method in a `static` class can be an extension method.

Comment: what does extension mean here?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

Unlike a non-static class you cannot modify the static method to be an instance method later, because a static class can only contain static members.

This is not allowed and will not compile

```
public static class Foo{
    public void test(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A static class can contain only static methods, whereas a non-static class can contain both. Deciding which way to go is strictly a design issue in C#.